# Android: gravity property in style.xml does not work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, styles

the result

[image]

the desired

[image]

I'm trying to get the desired apperience in which text is in the middle of the textview but with no success could you help please what should I do?

(NOT: when I put this property to textview itself it works but not in style.xml - I need to manage gravity issue in style xml because there is too much rows and colums in my layout)

style.xml

```
    <style name="Normal">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

my_layout.xml

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Column 1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Column 2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Normal" />
</TableRow>
```

**[EDIT]:**  textSize affects the apperience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

Try this for me?

Comment: do it on the layout containing the textviews.

Comment: you mean out of the table layout ?

Comment: put in the table row then.

Comment: put weightSum as 2 for TableRow